# 64gb SDXC Cards in Galaxy S2, or 64gb SDXC cards where only 32gb supported

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-sd, sd-card, formatting

I spent *hours* looking for a solution to my issues with my 64gb Micro SDXC card that my girlfriend purchased me for my birthday.

From what I understand only capacities up to 32gb are officially supported. But thread after thread informed me that users of my phone had successfully used one. When I first plugged in my SD my phone said "Preparing SD card" and then, after a brief pause, "SD Card safe to remove". The card wasn't mounting.

I tried inserting it into my SD adapter and formatting in NTFS on my laptop. Side note - whoever designed SD adapters and ports can go straight to hell. I was terrified of damaging my expensive new card since it got stuck in the adapter, and the adapter left 1mm of space outside my laptop. Holy crap.

After formatting in NTFS the phone informed me it'd have to reformat the SD card. Progress, I thought, until after the formatting message I had the same issue.

I thought maybe my firmware was the issue and spent a couple hours trying to figure out how to jailbreak. Long story short I gave up.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Ryanman! Thanks for sharing your problem *and solution*, that's great and useful! But may we ask you to place the solution into an *answer*? As it stands now, your post looks like a problem without any answer when viewed from a list. Sure I could do that for you, but I don't want to steal your reputation and declare it mine :) // Btw, a remark: Android does not (natively) support NTFS, which is why your second try failed. Same applies to ExFAT, as far as I know.

Comment: Absolutely @Izzy ! Right now I have to wait to answer this officially as an answer (8 hours) since this is a "new" account, but I have an alarm set and will do it as soon as possible.

And thank you for the xtra info. I figured with Microsoft's control over ExFAT it might be an issue. I was hoping that with an NTFS formatted card that Android could at least recognize it and reformat in FAT on its own but at least I didn't blow $40 on this SD card for nothing!

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely correct! I completely forgot about that new-user-restriction. Great you're on it! Ping me again to upvote when done :) I'm in a comparable situation (with a 32G limited device). Your solution made me re-think about whether I should give it a try. As a Linux-guy, I had the added chance of using ext4, which is supported by Android. And as author of Android books, I could at least blame the expense at taxes partly (business-expense), so the "loss" wouldn't hit that hard :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Solution:** Thanks to the guys on [This Thread](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-t-mobile/615936-galaxy-s2-not-reading-64gb-sdxc.html) I figured it out. I also used the same tool they described, Minitool Partition Wizard, though I'm sure you could use any partition tool.

In windows on an SDXC card you can only format in ExFAT and NTFS. With a third party tool, you can make the card a FAT partition. Once you do this, the card is recognized in my S2 with no issues. I assume this will work with other phones that have "grey" support for large capacity SDXC cards.

Hope this helped y'all!

Answer (score 2):

As well as being in the right format, there are two types of SDXC cards. For devices that say that cards above 32gb may not be supported, they only support the V2 Sd card, and devices that say they support above 32gb, the take both v2 and v3. V1 is now redundant.