# Do all microSD slots support the current maximum capacity in the market, or is it device-specific?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, storage

I know that currently (Dec 2013), microSD capacity is up to 64GB.

However reading some devices' specs, it says "includes microSD card slot, up to 32GB", is it a device restriction, or it's because it was written before 64GB cards were available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will most likely depend on the device, a generic answer valid for all of them cannot be given. For example, the *Samsung Galaxy S2* specs give 32 GB as max, still some user was able to get a 64 GB card working (see: [64gb SDXC Cards in Galaxy S2](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/58782/16575)). For some older devices, the 32 GB limit might be a fact, while again others might just have specified it to be "on the safe site".

TL;DR: **Yes, it's device dependant, some devices have their limits.**